# Programmatically open password-protected SQLite database with given password

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encryption

I have a password-protected SQLite database. I know the password, and let's say it is `123456qwAS`.

I want to embed this password into my app so that my app can open the database automatically. Before this database was password-protected, I had used the following code to open the database:

```
public void showWordlist()
{
    edWord.setEnabled(true);
    String word = edWord.getText().toString();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://myapp_Provider/dict/" + mDBFile.fileName + "/list/" + word);
    edWord.requestFocus();      
    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor result = managedQuery(uri,null,null,null,null);          
        if (result != null)
        {
            int countRow=result.getCount();
            Log.i(MAIN_TAG, "countRow = " + countRow);
            mLSTCurrentWord.clear();
            //mLSTCurrentContent.clear();
            mLSTCurrentWordId.clear();
            mAdapter.clear();
            if (countRow >= 1)
            {
                int indexWordColumn = result.getColumnIndex("word");
                int indexIdColumn = result.getColumnIndex("id");
                result.moveToFirst();
                String strWord;
                int intId;

                int i = 0;
                do
                {
                    strWord = Utility.decodeContent(result.getString(indexWordColumn));
                    intId = result.getInt(indexIdColumn);
                    mLSTCurrentWord.add(i,strWord);
                    mLSTCurrentWordId.add(i,intId);
                    mAdapter.add(strWord);
                    i++;
                } while (result.moveToNext()); 
            }       
            result.close();
        }
        lstWord.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(MAIN_TAG, "Error = " + ex.toString());  
    }
    edWord.setEnabled(true);        
}
```

So it comes to my question: **How can I programmatically add the above password to this code so that my app can open (and load) the password-protected database automatically?**

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't support encrypted/password-protected SQLite manipulation. As an alternate, you may integrate [H2 Database](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) which claims to offer such protection at a cost of almost 1MB overhead.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but to be honest I think there might be a mechanism to check the state of the SQLite db before opening it. Is that a deadlock?

Comment: haven't heard of any mechanism for android. can you post some reference links?